# javascript: value increase continuously

Tags: php, javascript, html

I knew it's just a simple problem. But I still can't fix it. What I want is the output value will increase continuously when I click the button, and here's my code:

```
$('.submit').live('vclick', function(){
var x = 0;
x+=1;
document.getElementById('plus').innerHTML = x;
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var x = 0;
$('.submit').on('vclick', function(){
    x = parseInt(document.getElementById('plus').innerHTML);
    x += 1;
    document.getElementById('plus').innerHTML = x;
});
```

Dont use `live` because it is **depricated**.Instead use `on` in place of `live`.
Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuGWN/)

Comment: Rather than using x = document.getElementById('plus').innerHTML;
you can also use x=parseInt($('#plus').html());

Comment: See my fiddle in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Better use jQuery.data to store some variables point to DOM element

```
$(document).on('vclick', '.submit', function(){
    var el = $('#plus');
    var x = $(el).data('x') || 0;
    el.html(++x);
    $(this).data('x', x);
});
```